# Why are ForwardIterators required to model DefaultConstructible?

Tags: c++, iterator

I cannot seem to find any standard algorithms that would demonstrate the requirement for default-constructing a `ForwardIterator`.

Is there any actual reason for it, or am I safe to ignore it?

Comment: It doesn't matter if there's an actual reason for it; it's *required*. So ignore the requirement at your peril.

Comment: Well, if the iterator logically relies on an argument, the alternative is to add default constructors that leave the object in an invalid state, which also seems flirting with peril.

Comment: A *working* alternative would be to change your iterators so that they don't rely on an argument. Put them in a valid but conceptually empty state.

Comment: I suppose throwing an exception from the default constructor would possibly be ok - otherwise, you really need to test in every single function of the iterator for that invalid state.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that when they wrote the DefaultConstructible requirement, they kinda expected the constructor to, you know, complete. "otherwise, you really need to test in every single function of the iterator for that invalid state." No, you don't. Iterators outside of the range (and default-constructed iterators are outside of the range) are not required to be valid, in the sense that calling * or ++ will yield defined behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is there to ease the use of these kind of iterators, for both the standard algorithms and client users.

For example (remember that `RandomAccessIterator` is a subtype of `ForwardIterator`):

```
template <class RandomAccessIterator>
  void sort ( RandomAccessIterator first, RandomAccessIterator last )
{
    RandomAccessIterator pivot, i, j;
    //do your sorting algorithm        
}
```

If they were not default constructible you would need to assign them to `first` or `last` just for it to compile.

You do not need it to be set to a default value. Any use of such uninitialized iterator is undefined. Not that is would not be wise to add some check, particularly in debug builds.

And no, you should not throw in the default constructor. It would be technically conformant, but many algorithms will fail unexpectedly.

Comment: That's an argument for `RandomAccessIterator` to model `DefaultConstructible`, not `ForwardIterator`, though. `InputIterator` is not required to model `DefaultConstructible`, why `ForwardIterator`?

Comment: Not to mention, I don't know if allowing dubiously easier implementation of standard algorithms is worth the unnecessary requirement that disallows all usage of references and other non-default-constructible types. It has far-reaching implications throughout all your data types - suddenly, everything that iterator uses must also now allow default construction and a "constructed but invalid" state.

Comment: Well that sort of code would be against RAII based coding guidelines where initialization is mandated at the point of definition.

Comment: @Ayjay - I may agree with you... but that is the Standard requirement, and you should better follow it. Doing a quick search in the G++ STL headers (gcc 4.7), I've found only one such use of default initialized iterators (other than the check for proper iterators and default constructors of other iterators): in `ForwardIterator partition_point(ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last, Predicate pred)`, and that could easily have been avoided.

Comment: It seems that MSVC v10 also uses it in `adjacent_find` and `unique`, again avoidably so. How frustrating, to be required to add support for invalid states to iterators merely to appease a bug in the standard. Sigh, the C++ standard strikes again.

Answer (score 3):

From my copy of the draft:

> **24.2.5 Forward iterators [forward.iterators]**
>
> **1** A class or a built-in type X satisfies the requirements of a forward iterator if
>
> [...]
>
> — X satisfies the DefaultConstructible requirements (20.2.1),

and then:

> **20.2.1 Template argument requirements**
>
> **2** In general, a default constructor is not required. Certain container
> class member function signatures specify the default constructor as a
> default argument. T() shall be a well-defined expression (8.5) if one
> of those signatures is called using the default argument (8.3.6).

There are two things to note here:

- The first line tells us that a default ctor is rarely required (which almost answers your question)
- The requirement is probably a hint that iterator semantics should be compatible with pointers, the latter being default constructible (read not to break existing code).

Comment: That seems to imply that ForwardIterator need be DefaultConstructible iff you call one of those "certain container class member function signatures" with it. Does the standard specify any times when that must occur?

Comment: @Ayjay: The standard should provide any such member functions. I can't name one off the cuff, but I wouldn't be surprised if there aren't any. That should indicate to me that this was byway of cutting future library writers some slack.